# How to designite with @ApiResponse code, message and class that would be just forwarded from the other HTTP call, initiated by the current?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, resttemplate

We have the API Controller, that returns

```
return restTemplate.getForEntity(uriRestartNO.toUri(), SuccessDTO.class);
```

So now in Swagger annotation we need to annotate not only the expected

```
@ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success", response = SuccessDTO.class)
    }
```

But also all the possible error case, that will just to resend all non-expected result. How to forward all the structures and response codes and how to designate that with Swagger, that our backend doesn't produce own response structure on failure, but resends whatever was sent to it? (I know that is a bad idea, but have to follow this requirement)